# Having trouble joining 2 tables in Oracle SQL Server in query

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two tables, `LGINVOICE` and `LGCUSTOMER` that have the following columns:

- `LGINVOICE`: INV_NUM, INV_DATE, CUST_CODE, INV_TOTAL, EMPLOYEE_ID
- `LGCUSTOMER`: CUST_CODE, CUST_FNAME, CUSTLNAME, CUST_BALANCE

My question is, I need to show the customer code, first name, last name, and a sum of all invoice totals for customers with a cumulative invoice total greater than $1,500 and the sort the output by the sum of the invoice totals in descending order.

I've got the sorting and whatnot complete (as shown in the SQL code below) but am having trouble with the join required to make the first and last names show up in the query result. I am fairly new to SQL and would appreciate the help!

My query:

```
SELECT CUST_CODE, SUM(INV_TOTAL) AS TOTALINVOICE
FROM LGINVOICE
GROUP BY CUST_CODE
HAVING SUM(INV_TOTAL) > 1500
ORDER BY TOTALINVOICE DESC;
```

It currently results in the correct `CUST_CODE` and `TOTALINVOICE` output in the correct order. I just don't know how to properly join the customer table to allow for the first and last name columns showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `JOIN`.  One method does the `JOIN` before the aggregation:

```
SELECT c.CUST_FNAME, c.CUSTLNAME, i.CUST_CODE, SUM(i.INV_TOTAL) AS TOTALINVOICE
FROM LGINVOICE i JOIN
     LGCUSTOMER c
     ON c.CUST_CODE = i.CUST_CODE
GROUP BY c.CUST_FNAME, c.CUSTLNAME, i.CUST_CODE
HAVING SUM(i.INV_TOTAL) > 1500
ORDER BY TOTALINVOICE DESC;
```

Comment: Wow fast response. This is the correct answer. Will mark it when the required time passes! Thanks!